# Ubuntu in Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, emulator, virtualbox

In my computer I have two operation systems Ubuntu and Windows. Usually I working in linux, but sometimes I should working in windows. Can I start in emulator my Ubuntu from another hard drive in Windows?

Comment: So, let me get this straight. You have Ubuntu and Windows installed on your machine. You want to know if you can use Windows and start your existing Ubuntu installation in a virtual machine. Is that it?

Comment: Yes. I'm android and windows phone developer. For android I use Ubuntu for WP - windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VirtualBox: using physical partition as virtual drive](http://superuser.com/questions/392601/virtualbox-using-physical-partition-as-virtual-drive). Also see [Booting into a Virtual Machine from a physical installation](http://superuser.com/questions/69915/booting-into-a-virtual-machine-from-a-physical-installation) and similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you are using [multi boot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi_boot) on your computer, and now you want to run your existing Ubuntu installation inside a virtual machine.

Apparently, this is possible with VMware. See if [this](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_disk_dualboot.html) is of any help to you.
From this second hyperlink:

> Many users install VMware Workstation on a dual-boot or multiple-boot computer so they can run one or more of the existing operating systems in a virtual machine. If you are doing this, you may want to use the existing installation of an operating system rather than reinstall it in a virtual machine.