# Store Virtualbox Guest Files on Host OS

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, debian

**Background:** I'm running Windows 7 as a host and Debian as a guest OS.  I often create backups of the hard drive, but run into the issue that my files are stored in 2 locations, Windows NTFS volume and in the Virtualbox file system(.vdi).  I often you use the internet to make such backups, and having such a large .vdi is troublesome.  In addition I often have to resize the debian.vdi to allow for more files.  I have used a shared folder, but the speed isn't always fast enough and permissions do not hold.

**Question:** I would like to store all Debian files on the Host OS so I can easily view them between both OS's and simplify the backup process.

From my understanding I can use the following command to mount my shared directories from HOST OS in Debian `mount -t vboxsf host_os host_os`.

Can I store the Debian folders `bin etc media proc selinux  tmp 
boot  home lib mnt root  srv usr 
dev   lost+found      opt    sbin  sys      var` on the Windows 7 NTFS file system?

It seems I might be able to do something like `mount -t vboxsf home /home`.  Similary I could do the same for `/var` and `/tmp`, but I don't understand the internals to know if I can do it for all the root directories.

**EDIT:** NTFS doesn't have proper unix file permissions, so it might require a Samba running in a VM.  Still not entirely sure though.

Answer (score 0):

To view Debian's files in host OS you could go like this:

1. Create a physical particion on your hard drive.
2. [Make a virtual disk out of it](https://superuser.com/a/437952/130459) and attach it to the virtual machine.
3. Install (or move) Debian on it.
4. Use [`ext2fsd`](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) or a similar driver to access files on that partition from your Windows host.

But while this could supposedly (almost) directly implement what you asked, I think this solution is suboptimal:

- Somewhat cumbersome to implement.
- Your backups with regard to guest OS files would be essentially readonly beacuse I'm not sure any `extN` filesystem driver for Windows is 100% bullet-proof when it will come to restoring. At least this have to be tested.

So I would probably take another route:

- When you back up the host OS, exclude the guest's virtual disk file.
- Back up the guest separately, using the guest's own means.

As to the last bit your question — no, Samba has nothing to do with your situation: it implements "Windows file and printer sharing" on the host it runs on, that is, it exports the host's own resources.  It *is* also possible to mount network shares exported by some other Windows host but this a) requires a network; b) I doubt anyone thought of making Debian be able to mount its essential "static" filesystems off Windows shares; it's definitely doable for NFS, but via SMB — I really doubt.

Comment: I was referring to the idea of installing Samba in the VM so that I could store all my Windows files basically in the VM.  There is a network option in Virtualbox so I believe it could be possible with if nothing at least some port forwarding.

Comment: I not seriously considering the Samba option because I have feeling the speed will be terrible.  Possible another solution would involving using `ext2` http://www.fs-driver.org/  It might be more stable then ext3 considering how long ext2 has been around.

Comment: I am using a separate computer & operating system right now(ubuntu) to essentially mount the external drive over samba.  It seems to work well enough for now.  I ssh into the machine and simply work on it that way.